# NAS backup not working

Tags: backup, nas, synology

I have the following Setup:

[image]

Before today, I only had 2 NAS storage units. NAS 1 and NAS 2 and they were being backupped to a remote server.

Today I have bought a third NAS (NAS 3) and I have used to Synology setup to automatically backup every day from NAS 1 and 2 to NAS 3.

The settings on nas 1 and 2 are exactly the same, except for the firmware version.

NAS 1 backups perfectly to NAS 3

NAS 2 however, gives me the following error:

```
Connection failed. Check your network settings 
(roughly translated)
```

It is not that NAS 3 is invisible for NAS 2, because when I enter the wrong username or password, the software won't let me see the backup folder on NAS3

And if I do enter the right username and password, I can choose wich map to backup to.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the use of Jumbo frames. Synology does not support jumbo frames if you are using the NAS to backup. Disabling Jumbo frames has solved the issue